# Tag for NppExec as a support to Notepad++

Tags: support, status-completed

How are new tags decided? Is this done if there are say 50 or so questions containing a particular topic? I obviously don't have the reputation to create new tags, but being a regular user of Notepad++/NppExec I'd like to see a separate tag [nppexec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/nppexec) to go with [notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b). The current questions related to NppExec don't have suitable tags and it makes it difficult to track specific NppExec questions marked with a [notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b) tag.

The [nppexec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/nppexec) tag has already been created on SO. Would it be possible to have it on Super User too?

Comment: If you give me a link to a question where the nppexec tag would be appropriate, I'll go make the tag for you. As long as somebody has enough rep to create new tags, all it takes is one person to make it.

Comment: Here it is: http://superuser.com/questions/381942/stop-nppexec-from-trapping-console-output-until-program-finishes

Comment: This one's more recent: http://superuser.com/questions/412491/running-macro-through-nppexec-notepad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I created [nppexec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/nppexec). You probably know more about it than I do, so if you'd like to go ahead and [edit the tag wiki description](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/nppexec), that'd be very helpful!

Comment: I just did. It's been placed in review. Thanks a ton!